# How to add a function that prints out Output for URLSession.DataTaskPublisher but not calling sink?

Tags: combine, urlsession

I want to add a function you can call when using URLSession.DataTaskPublisher to fetch output from a `URLRequest`, that can print out the request and the data (whenever they are received.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!)
            .logEvents()  
            .map { data, _ in return data }
            .decode(type: [Post].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .sink { ///  .. handles the sinked values }
```

where the `logEvents()` function should print out the data, and the response object to console, or error if it fails. For `URLSession.dataTask` i've written it like this:

```
func dataTask(withLogging request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    return self.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        URLRequest.debugPrintYAML(request: request, response: response, received: data, error: error)
        completionHandler(data, response, error)
    }
}
```

this just replaces `dataTask(with:`, with `dataTask(withLogging:`, and makes it really easy to see good console logs of all requests that are called using it. The goal i'm doing is to write a similar function for the Publisher version, `dataTaskPublisher`

what i would like the .logEvents()  to do is calling the same

```
URLRequest.debugPrintYAML(request: request, response: response, received: data, error: error)
```

What i've tried:

**doing it in `.map`:**

I have access to `data` and `response` there, but i have to change the return type of the function, and i don't really want to to that in a generic logging function. Also having it as a side effect in a map function isn't really optimal, that function should only map. This is what i've tried in the example given below

**doing it in `.sink`:**

Since i allready have mapped to responses by the time i get to the .sink, i have lost the information about response and data, which means i ofc cant write them out.

**doing it in `.handleEvents` inside a function:**

If i use `.handleEvents`, i don't really have a place to store the cancellable, and i'm allready creating a `Cancellable` when calling `.sink` later, so having two cancellables is not optimal.

```
extension Publisher where Output == (data: Data, response: URLResponse),
                        Self == URLSession.DataTaskPublisher
{
func logEvents() -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {
        let cancellable = self.handleEvents { values in
            print(values.description)
        }
        // the cancellable is not retained, and therefore this will never fire
        return self
    }
}
```

This extension is open source and [located here](https://github.com/BeiningBogen/URLRequest-console-logging/blob/main/URLRequest%2BLogging.swift)

Comment: Have you tried using the `handleEvents` publisher operator?  It is designed to help you add "side effects" to a combine pipeline.

Comment: @ScottThompson i updated the question with my problems with doing it in handleEvents. Maybe i have something wrong? Appreciate any comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

fileprivate func logOneEvent(data: Data, response: URLResponse) {
    print("Got \(data.count) bytes")
    print("Response: \(response)")
}

extension Publisher where Output == URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output
{
    func logEvents() -> Publishers.HandleEvents<Self> {
        return self.handleEvents(receiveOutput: logOneEvent)
    }
}

let jsonURL = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
let subscription = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: jsonURL)
    .logEvents()
    .sink { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            print("Done")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Failed \(error)")
        }

    } receiveValue:  {
        debugPrint($0)
    }
```

A publisher (in this case a `Publishers.HandleEvents` instance) is a thing you can return from a function like `logEvents`.  You can just let that thing handle subscriptions normally, there's no need to try and inject and maintain your own subscription.